# Can it be undecidable whether a problem is undecidable or not?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability

I've just started learning about the concept of undecidability and turing machines, and while I am finally beginning to grasp it, I'm still curious about one thing. Is it possible for a problem to exist for which it is impossible to prove whether it is undecidable or not? In other words, can the problem of "is it decidable" be undecidable itself?

There could be a serious contradiction that I'm not missing here, but I'm not sure. Are there any problems known like this?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, which is hard to answer,or even to formulate. One of the points is that we need a formalism the specify "problems". The question has been asked before: "[Is Deciding Decidability Decidable?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/42198/4287)" With some care, the problem can be argued to be undecidable.